# Changing the design systems in on the level of Atoms (Reference to Atomic Design System)

Tags: product-design, product-management, product

I work a product design manager and planning to change the mobile apps designs on Atomic Level, like changing User Interface Elements which are checkboxes, radio buttons, dropdown lists, list boxes, buttons, toggles, text fields, date field, breadcrumb, slider, search field, pagination, slider, tags, icons, tooltips, icons, progress bar, notifications, message boxes, modal windows, accordion

I want to write product brief to help the business understand what will be the outcome of this exercise. Basically want to explain the stakeholder the business matrix to do this exercise.

Anyone can help me in this?

Comment: This question is very broad, can you explain in detail what exactly you are struggling with? 1. Why do you want to make those changes? 2. Is this just visual change or refractoring the components? 3. What are the user painpoints you try to solve by this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.